# React useEffect() state isn't updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when Im using the useEffect hook with the setState hook, the state isn't updated if I only want the useEffect to run once (i.e. pass an empty array as the second parameter).

If i pass the array that Im updating as the second parameter, the state gets updated but then the useEffect keeps running in an infinite loop...

Here is the code that Im trying to run:
In this example when printing out memes or endPage - they still hold their initial state values ([] and 0)

```
function ImageContainer() {
  const [memes, setMemes] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndex, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentPage, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [endPage, setEndPage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMemes(currentPage).then((data) => {
      setEndPage(data.pagination.totalPages);
      setMemes(data.data);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(memes);
      console.log(endPage);
    });
  }, []);
```

[image]

but if I pass memes as the second parameter:

```
function ImageContainer() {
  const [memes, setMemes] = useState([]);
  const [currentIndex, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [currentPage, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [endPage, setEndPage] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMemes(currentPage).then((data) => {
      setEndPage(data.pagination.totalPages);
      setMemes(data.data);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(memes);
      console.log(endPage);
    });
  }, [memes]);
```

Then the console.log shows that both of the states have been updated, but the code keeps looping infinitely.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you should pass `currentPage` instead of memes in the array as your `getMemes` method seems to depend on `currentPage`. If you pass `memes`, it'll be stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @rishabh0211 if i pass the currentPage, i get the first scenario (state still isnt getting updated)

Comment: You state must be getting updated. State updation is an asynchronous task. But you are logging it to console just after that. That's why you are not seeing it on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state will get updated but the issue here is that you are checking for state updates by calling `console.log(memes)` directly after `setMemes(data.data)`, but the state of a component is updated **asynchronously** which means `setMemes` is an asynchronous function.

If you want to do something with `memes` (except updating it) after it has been updated use another `useEffect` hook and define `memes` as its dependency.

The infinite loop is happening because you are defining `memes` as dependency of the `useEffect` and also updating `memes` inside the same effect. Therefore this `useEffect` is constantly triggering itself.

Comment: The only place where I use the meme array is when I try to render it as so:
  return (
    <div className="imageContainer">
      <div className="memeContainer">
        <img src={memes[currentIndex].aws_url} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

The reason that  I assume that the state isnt getting updated, is because the app crashes trying to get a parameter from a null object

Comment: @MarkwinVI If you are only using `memes` for rendering than you don't need another `useEffect`.
Please post the error message.  Which object is `null` and which parameter are you trying to access?

Comment: The object array that I get from the BE is as follows
`(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
aws_url: "https://memesupply-memes.s3.amazonaws.com/1593899865516"
createdAt: "2020-07-04T21:57:49.031Z"
draft: false
updatedAt: "2020-07-04T21:57:49.031Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5f00fb5d3d7379325300c4fe"`

Then on my render I try to access the object like so:

 `src={memes[currentIndex].aws_url} `

But i get the following error message:

`Cannot read property 'aws_url' of undefined`

Comment: @MarkwinVI This might be related to your problem but not to this question you posted, so this comment section isn't really appropriate for further investigation. Please open a new question.

Comment: Thanks, but just managed to solve it myself. Turns out you have to wait a bit before rendering async data:

`{memes[0] ? (
          <img src={memes[currentIndex].aws_url} alt="" />
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}`

This did the trick

Comment: @MarkwinVI Glad to hear that you have resolved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

It get stacked in infinite loop because the closure you passed to the function then set the state of memes, that trigger the useEffect hook, because it's listening the state of the property memes. You can pass currentPage in the array. Try using a loading state.

Answer (score 0):

You needlessly create an infinite loop by adding memes to the effect dependency, log it in the component function instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getMemes(currentPage).then((data) => {
    setEndPage(data.pagination.totalPages);
    setMemes(data.data);
    console.log('api data:',data);
  });
}, []);
console.log('memes:',memes);
console.log('end page:',endPage);
```