# how to call ".hidden.bs.dropdown" event using jquery inside react function component

Tags: reactjs

I have a multi select dropdown. I am trying to call a function on dropdown close with all selected values but selected items are always empty.

```js
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);
const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {   
    if(!isDropdownLoading)
            $(dropdownRef.current).on("hidden.bs.dropdown", e => {
                onDropdownClose(selectedItems);
        //This function is getting called on dropdown close but selectedItems is always empty array.
            });
        }
    }, [isDropdownLoading]);
  
  const toggleItem=(event,selectedItem)=>{
    //here logic to find selected items and update state
    setSelectedItems(ArrayWithSelectedItems);
  }
```

```html
if (isDropdownLoading) {
        return <p className="drop-down-onloading">Loading...</p>;
    }

return (
        <div ref={dropdownRef}>
            <button         
                type="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
                title={titleText}   
                
            >
                {name}
            </button>
            <div className="dropdown-menu"> 
                {dropDownList.map(item => {
                    if (item.isVisible) {
                        return (
                            <button
                                className="dropdown-item"                               
                                onClick={e => toggleItem(e, item)}
                                key={item.id}
                                id={name}
                            >
                                <i
                                    className={`${
                                        item.isChecked
                                            ? "check-box"
                                            : "empty-box"
                                    }`}
                                ></i>
                                {item.name}
                            </button>
                        );
                    }
                })}
            
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Why state is always empty array inside Jquery event. This is a function based react component.

Comment: Where did you selectedItems while rendering ?

Comment: @Tuhin dropDownList prop has items to display. once user click on items in the dropdown it updates isChecked property of dropDownlist array also set state selectedItem by called state method setSelectedItem. On dropdown close I am trying to pass find selected Items.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62762358/react-useeffect-state-isnt-updated

Comment: @Tuhin My component has many other states and all states has default values inside jquery event. I know state update is async but here problem is not that. I am looking for answer how to call ".hidden.bs.dropdown" event using jquery inside function based component with access to react js state.